# does the following program cause memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-management, pipe

I have been running this code with valgrind and the valgrind shows there are no memory leaks, despite the fact that I didn't close fd_read why is that?

edit:

this question showed up in one of my exams, according to my professor the correct answer is that there was memory leaking in that program. does file descriptors leaking is considered memory leaking?

```
   int main(int argc,char** argv){
     int fds[2];
     int fd_read,fd_write;
     if(pipe(fds)==-1){
       perror("Error");
       exit(1);
     }
     fd_read=fds[0];
     fd_write=fds[1];
     close(1);
     dup(fd_write);
     close(fd_write);
     printf("Done");
     return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `open`, `pipe`, or `dup` to "allocate" low-level, integer file descriptors does not allocate any user memory and so does not constitute a memory leak if they're not closed.

Now, with that said, this program can be said to "leak" file descriptors, and that's another kind of resource leakage that can be a problem in long-running programs, although for whatever reason it doesn't usually end up being nearly so much of a problem in practice.

(And of course, under any sane operating system, open file descriptors are definitively closed on exit, just as still-allocated memory is effectively but definitively freed.  So pretty much nobody worries about fd leaks on non-long-running programs.)

Answer (score 2):

No memory is leaked in you case, mainly because open is a system call here. If there were leaks, valgrind would point them anyway.

That said, opening files *may* allocated memory in low level libs (say you call fopen instead of open), mainly to store 'handle' on the files themselves.

In the end, on usual OS, the kernel is able to close the files you may have opened and to get back the memory you may have forgot to free on exit, so one could wonder who cares. It is generally considered as a bad practice not to cleanup things before leaving, even if not really harmful in the end.

you may track left unclosed files using:

```
valgrind --track-fds=yes ./a.out
```

In your case I get:

```
==30758== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30758== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30758== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30758== Command: ./a.out
==30758== 
==30758== 
==30758== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 7 open at exit.
==30758== Open file descriptor 1:
==30758==    at 0x4F26637: dup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==30758==    by 0x4006A9: main (in a.out)
==30758== 
==30758== Open file descriptor 3:
==30758==    at 0x4F266C7: pipe (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so)
==30758==    by 0x400670: main (in a.out)
==30758== 
==30758== Open file descriptor 38: /usr/share/applications/org.kde.akonadiimportwizard.desktop
==30758==    <inherited from parent>
==30758== 
==30758== Open file descriptor 27:
==30758==    <inherited from parent>
==30758== 
==30758== Open file descriptor 26:
==30758==    <inherited from parent>
==30758== 
==30758== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/16
==30758==    <inherited from parent>
==30758== 
==30758== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/16
==30758==    <inherited from parent>
==30758== 
==30758== 
==30758== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30758==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30758==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4,096 bytes allocated
==30758== 
==30758== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30758== 
==30758== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30758== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: No memory's allocated as it's all from system calls which deal with integers only for the process.

Comment: You said in your answer that memory was allocated in system libraries to store the handles, but no memory is allocated by the program for handling these files.

Comment: this I cannot know on standard programs; say you use fopen instead of open, there will be memory leaked by the software as some memory will be allocated in libc. Here, we just do open, while "luckily" is a system call (which you cannot really know in first place unless you explicitly perform the system call by hand)

Comment: That contradicts your answer completely, but you be you.

Comment: @teppic It's true that `open` *usually* returns small descriptors that refer solely to data structures allocated in the OS kernel, but I've used at least one system (some version of MacOS) where the more "fundamental" way of opening a file was `fopen`, and a Unix-compatible `open` was actually implemented as a wrapper function around `open`.  So in that case I'm pretty sure `open` would have been allocating memory in user/application space.

Comment: @SteveSummit Sure. But we're talking about POSIX pipes, and the answer used valgrind output, so my comments were in the context of the answer (a specific), not a hypothetical operating system where we have to guess what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not leaking memory, you are leaking file descriptors. Valgrind doesn't track those, so it won't show you leaking them.

If you had long running process that created lots of pipes or opened lots of files and forgot to close them, you could run out of file descriptors for that process. The limit is set by the system administrator, and usually sits around 1024 or more. After that the pipe or open syscalls would return -1 to signal failure with errno ENFILE.